# FastAPI sending from websocket in subprocess

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

From the main loop I'm running:

```
task = Process(
            target=sub_process 
            args=(socket,),
            daemon=True
        )
```

Then in the `sub_process` I start a new asyncio event loop and call await socket.send_json(...) but it doesn't seem to be sending anything. I don't get any errors, I just can see anything on the client.. Any idea what is happening or remedies?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it didn't work but I used a queue to communicate with the main thread and then sent message from there instead.